# How to add a new table in Sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a DB in sqlite and a table in this DB. now i want to add one more table in this table.
But am not getting why this new table is not being in DB.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please add the statement you use to create the table and the exception (if any).

Comment: you have any table in your Sqlite now ya you want to add new table only...!!

Comment: can you clear little more as MIKE said.I am giving answer what i understand

Comment: Use the links I provided to do it correctly from the get go... Will save you so many headaches in the future.

Comment: Just a tip: with http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ you can open your sqlite database, browse and edit your data. And even check if your queries will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these two links. Sample code is in the second one:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

http://code.google.com/p/android-notes/source/browse/trunk/src/com/bitsetters/android/notes/DBHelper.java?r=10

You should use a helper class to access the DB and these links will help. If you do it correctly from the beginning, it will save you a lot of trouble when upgrading later down the road. Hope it helps.

Also, in the second link, the DBHelper.java, you can see the creation strings at the beginning of the file in case you are unaware of what to look for.

```
private static final String DBVERSION_CREATE = 
  "create table " + TABLE_DBVERSION + " ("
   + "version integer not null);";
private static final String NOTES_CREATE =
  "create table " + TABLE_NOTES + " ("
  + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
  + "note text, "
  + "lastedit text);";
```

Comment: sadly, the second link passed away. .

Answer (score 3):

I guess it sounds like an update problem. If you change your table columns or create new tables you need to update your DB.

```
SQLiteDatabase YourDatabaseName;
YourDatabaseName = getData.getWritableDatabase();
getData.onUpgrade(YourDatabaseName, 1, 2);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create new Table that is not exist then use this.Let you want to create table when btn clicked

```
        Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = databaseclassObject.getWritableDatabase();
            String str="create table tablename(Col1 text not null,col2 text not null);";
            db.execSQL(str);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a new table to database...

step 1: Increase database version

step 2: Create a new table in the method onUpgrade :

```
@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {  
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE COLUMN1 TEXT," +
            "COLUMN2 TEXT," +
            "COLUMN3 TEXT");  

 }  
}
```